# How to get url address of uploads folder in MVC 4, C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to create image tags in my View with url generated after an image was created by a controller method in "uploads" folder. I can hardcode my url address but that is not the way to do this. I need the real URL of my uploads folder wherever I deploy my application.

For example the uploads folder is at root level along the Views/Controllers/Models, like so

```
http://localhost:1350/uploads
```

How can I generate this url in C#/MVC 4 ?

Comment: `~/upload/image_1.png` (for example) would point there.

Comment: Where do I put this string?

Comment: i have created custom function name is GetFileUrl https://stackoverflow.com/a/44460600/3089009

Comment: did my answer work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
public static string GetFileUrl(string serverUrl, bool forceHttps)
{
    if (serverUrl.IndexOf("://") > -1)
        return serverUrl;

    string resultUrl = serverUrl;
    Uri originalUri = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
    resultUrl = (forceHttps ? "https" : originalUri.Scheme) +
        "://" + originalUri.Authority + resultUrl;
    return resultUrl ;
} 

var url = GetFileUrl(VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/uploads/"),false))
```

Comment: I have my working environment on my job computer. Will have to try it. I think I used Request.Url and replaced the last bit of "api/upload" which was address for my upload controller with "uploads". But I haven't thought of https, so you get one upvote for that. I will try it on monday.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need:

```
string pathToFiles = Server.MapPath("/Uploads")
```

You can read more on this [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Sadly this gives my absolute path of the "uploads" folder on the disk. I need URL path of it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this ?

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads");
```

Way to get URL :

```
  var currentServerURL = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority +     Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd('/') + "/";
```

Comment: I don't want absolute path on the disk.

Comment: @Vlad, I have updated my answer by which you can get the live URL of your application.